# Fade in and out two elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to fade in and fade out multiple elements when a button is clicked.

For example.

When `item1` is clicked then it should fade in `first` and fade out `second`

#### [Example Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/75usquoL/)

**Code:**

```
<div id="menu" class="menu">
        <ul class="headlines">
             <li id="item1"onclick="checklist(this)"><button onclick="myFunction()">A</button></li>
            <li id="item2"><button onclick="myFunction2()">B</button></li>
            
        </ul>
        </div>

<div id="first">
<img id="image1" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150"/>
<img id="image2" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150"/>
<img id="image3" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150"/>
<img id="image4" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150"/>
</div>
      

        <div id="second">
        This is my DIV2 element.
    </div>

<script>
 function myFunction() {
    $("#second").fadeOut(2000, function(){
        $("first").fadeIn(6000);
    });
}
<script/>

<script>
   function myFunction2() {
    $("first").fadeOut(2000, function(){
        $("#second").fadeIn(6000);
    });
}
<script/>
```

CSS:

```
li{
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    height: 40px;
    width: 180px;
    text-align:right;    
    border-style: none;
    
}

.menu{

    width:150px;
    height: 350px;
 
   }

.menu li{  
position: relative;
  top:150px; 
  bottom: 0;
  left: 695px;
  right:0;
  margin: auto; 
  border-style:none;
    
}

#second {
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
            background-color: lightblue;
            display: none;
        }

#first
{
    width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
    background-color: red;
            display: none;
}
```

Comment: Okay fine, you try! `;)`

Comment: $("first").fadeIn(6000); - first is without a hash. #first

Comment: @PraveenKumar i tried as you can see, but there's something wrong.

Comment: @Zanuff still they didn't fade in and out

Comment: @randy Check my example

Comment: @randy it does work, but if you're using jsFiddle you need to set it to no wrap on the left, it is set with onLoad and your functions are not globally accessible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a quick tip before my example, I would recommend trying to get away from inline JavaScript and with you using JQuery I would definitely recommend it.

In this example it will show you how to fade the elements in on click of the buttons.

**JQuery clicking button Example:**

```js
$(document).on('click','#item1', function()
{ 
    $("#second").fadeOut(2000, function(){
        $("#first").fadeIn(6000);
    });

});


$(document).on('click','#item2', function()
{ 
    $("#first").fadeOut(2000, function(){
        $("#second").fadeIn(6000);
    });
});
```

```css
li{
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    height: 40px;
    width: 180px;
    text-align:right;    
    border-style: none;
    
}

.menu{

    width:150px;
    height: 350px;
 
   }

.menu li{  
position: relative;
  top:150px; 
  bottom: 0;
  left: 695px;
  right:0;
  margin: auto; 
  border-style:none;
    
}

#second {
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
            background-color: lightblue;
            display: none;
        }

#first
{
    width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
    background-color: red;
            display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="menu" class="menu">
        <ul class="headlines">
             <li id="item1"><button>A</button></li>
            <li id="item2"><button>B</button></li>
            
        </ul>
        </div>

<div id="first">
<img id="image1" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150"/>
<img id="image2" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150"/>
<img id="image3" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150"/>
<img id="image4" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150"/>
</div>
      

<div id="second">
   This is my DIV2 element.
</div>
```

Comment: just one question, can this work on several elements in the menu?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#item1").click(function() { 
        $("#first").fadeIn();
        $("#second").fadeOut();
    });
    $("#item2").click(function() { 
        $("#first").fadeOut();
        $("#second").fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Working **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/benLhjnd/)**

Answer (score 0):

In JSFiddle Don't use "ONCLICK"

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shiyam/75usquoL/11/)

```
$(".button_A").click(function(){
    $("#second").fadeOut(2000, function(){
        $("#first").fadeIn(6000);
    });
});

$(".button_B").click(function(){
    $("#first").fadeOut(2000, function(){
        $("#second").fadeIn(6000);
    });
});
```